# Google Sheets Calculate ROI in days

Tags: google-sheets, sum, match, days, roi

im trying to calculate the ROI in days for a specific case.
I start an investment amount with value X and every day i get different profits. All this separate profits get added everyday until the amount of the investment X is reached. The output should be the amount of sums which are equivalent to the days -> ROI in days

i googled already a bit but its very confusing for me.
do i need SUMIF or MATCH-function?
this seemed promising but it didnt work for me :(
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3865-excel-count-cells-until-value-is-reached.html

maybe the syntax in google sheets is slightly different? i dont know :(

hope someone can help me out with this. it cant be that difficult

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: hey, problem solved itself! with this formulas https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/target-sum-reached-row-in-google-sheets/